# VMWare Workstation on Windows 7: how can I enable Unity?

Tags: windows-7, vmware-workstation, vmware-unity

I'm running Windows 7 Guest on a Windows 7 Host. How can I enable Unity?

The guest OS is Windows 7 Ultimate 32-bit

The host OS is Windows 7 64-bit

---

I get the following error message "The virtual machine cannot enter Unity. Check that Unity is supported by this guest operating system and the latest version of VMWare Tools is installed"

Host has an ATI 3450 Video card with updated drivers.

Comment: To install VMWare Tools in the machine, click on **VM -> Install VMWare Tools**, that will allow you to enable Unity.

Comment: I've done that several times. I'll do it once more but it never let worked. I thought there was some hack OR maybe unsupported

Comment: You need to reboot the Virtual Machine, when it installs VMWare Tools, it connects a drive with the installation files and automatically starts up along with the VM.

Comment: Windows asks me if I want to run "setup". I click Setup then follow all on screen directions. I restarted the VM when prompted.But when I try Unity, VM appears to freeze for a few seconds then presents the message

Answer (score 0):

You can enable Unity by doing the following.

Click on **View -> Unity**

To start programs in Unity press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>

[image]